# How to create the related field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Model you see bellow:

```
class PriceModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

the `PriceModel`'s id is increased from `1`. I want to add other field, which is related to the `id`. Such as I want it to `#PM1`, `#PM2`... means the `#PM` + id.

How to create the related field?

Comment: Why a *field*, and *not* a property? Furthermore there is no fundamental guarantee that the id is incremented by one. In fact it can happen (in some databases) that due to concurrent transactions, and rollbacks, the `id` is sometimes incremented with 2 or more.

Comment: We could probably help you a lot more if you provided what you're trying to achieve, I think maybe you're looking for a solution which is maybe incorrectly designed for your goals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to add other field, which is related to the `id`. Such as I want it to `#PM1`, `#PM2`... means the `#PM + id`.

First of all, it is *not* guaranteed that for *all* database systems, the `id` is always incremented with one. For example if the database works with transactions, or other mechanisms, it is possible that a transaction is rolled back, and hence the corresponding `id` is never taken.

If you however want some "field" that always depends on the value of a field (here `id`), then I think a `@property` is probably a better idea:

```
class PriceModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)

    @property
    def other_field(self):
        return '#PM{}'.format(self.id)
```

So now if we have some `PriceModel`, then `some_pricemodel.other_field` will return a `'#PM123'` given (`id` is `123`). The nice thing is that if the `id` is changed, then the property will change as well, since it is each time calculated based on the fields.

A potential problem is that we can *not* make queries with this property, since the database does not know such property exists. We can however *define* an annotation:

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

PriceModel.objects.annotate(
    other_field=Concat(Value('#PM'), 'id')
).filter(
    other_field__icontains='pm1'
)
```

Comment: @qg_java_17137: well it is already specified, you do this in queries where you need to filter on the `other_field` as well. See *last* code fragment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can in your model serializer add a special field, rather than add a field in the Model.

```
class PriceModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ....
    show_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)


    class Meta:
        model = PriceModel

    def get_show_id(self):
        return '#PM' + self.id
```